# Outlook 2010 Managed Folders becomes "red"

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

One of my managed folder turned into red from black. What does that mean? Is there any place I can find the error message or log?

Few hours later, a notification box popped up saying "Rules in Error - the folder exceeded its storage quota". Is there any way to check what's the maximum quota? So I know how many emails I need to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Outlook, click on
File
Info
Cleanup Tools -> Mailbox Cleanup
Click View mailbox size

Comment: Cleanup is a way to fix the folder in red. But we still don't know why it's in red, nor check the rules.

Comment: It will tell you how much space the folder has and how much used... I would assume you are at quota